# Creating a 3-D (or larger) diagonal NumPy array from diagonals

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, numpy-ndarray

Is there an efficient 'Numpy'-based solution to create a 3 (or higher) dimensional diagonal matrix?

More specifically, I am looking for a shorter (and perhaps more efficient) solution to replace the following:

```
N = 100
M = 4
d = np.random.randn(N)   # calculated in the real use case from other parameters
A = np.zeros(M, M, N, dtype=d.dtype)
for i in range(M):
    A[i, i, :] = d
```

The above-mentioned solution will be slow if `M` is large, and I think not very memory-efficient as `d` is copied `M` times in the memory.

Answer (score 0):

Here's one with [`np.einsum`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.einsum.html) diag-view -

```
np.einsum('iij->ij',A)[:] =  d
```

Looking at the string notation, this also translates well from the iterative part : `A[i, i, :] = d`.

Generalize to ndarray with `ellipsis` -

```
np.einsum('ii...->i...',A)[:] =  d
```

Comment: But that still requires defining `A` in advance, am I right?  I was hoping to find something like `A = some_magic_function(d, M)`?

Comment: @kMaster And doing the initialization `A = np.zeros((M, M, N), dtype=d.dtype)` is bothering you?

Comment: Yes, mostly because this means we allocate `M*M*N` memory element for this array, whereas, only `N` elements should be sufficient to store such an array.

Comment: @kMaster You are looking to store in a sparse matrix probably? Sadly there's none for 3D or higher.